# Why can't I find this Map in roll20 that happens to be included in a module I bought?

Tags: roll20

I would like to show maps to my players of the town of Leilon (and Neverwinter, for that matter).

It's my first time using roll20, so I went through the tutorial. It says that under the "Art Library" tab, I can search for assets. I select "everything" in the dropdown, and enter "leilon" into the search field. I get a couple results in "From the Web," including some football players. None are what I want.

[image: No results for Leilon search]

I explore the app a bit more. From my campaign details page (outside the app itself), I find "Game Addons." I click "Essentials Kit: Divine Contention" from the dropdown, and click "Add to Game." It is added.

Now, when I launch my game, by coincidence the likes of which I've never experienced in my life, there's a Page in my game with a map of the town of Leilon, labeled with text tokens. I'll try to make similar pages with the same map!

[image: Page titled "Leilon Town Map" with leilon thumbnail]

I create a new page. I go to Art Library, and search "Everything" for Leilon. Now there's no results. I switch to Maps, Tiles, Textures in the dropdown just in case. Again, no results.

I go to the page that I guess came from the module I purchased. I switch to the "map and background" layer. I double click with the select tool, opening the "Edit Token" dialog. In here, I see nothing indicated the path of this map asset, under the basic or advanced tabs.

I go to the journal tab. I see a folder title "welcome to Leilon" and a note titled "exploring leilon" with a thumbnail matching the map. This opens a modal with the header being the map of leilon, with the text tokens applied (I guess this is a thumbnail capture of the entire page, then?) I click "edit," which shows that I can edit this image header. I click "delete," which replaces the image header with an option to drop or choose a file. Again, I can't locate this map anywhere.

I check under "art library" and click "my library." It's empty except for a couple duplicated archer tokens leftover, I guess, from the tutorial.

Where did this map of Leilon asset come from? Where is it being stored? Can I access it and do other things with it? Did I have to install this "Essentials Kit: Divine Contention" to use it? Are there other maps that the search feature can't find that I "own?" How can I find out? **Where is this map of Leilon asset stored?**

Comment: did you click on premium assets?  I will need to head home, but I discovered some of my maps in the map tab. Will follow up when I get to my PC with the stuf on it.

Comment: I can see a bunch of stuff under premium assets, but now I'm noticing something - for example, under premium -> free assets -> Pathfinder Second Edition... I see a bunch of tokens. Some are named in sequential numbering like "CRB Human (1, 2, etc)". So, I go back to search, and type "human." None of those assets show up, I only see "premium" and "from the web," and under "premium" I don't see any "CRB Human etc." Does search not work like I thought?

Comment: oh, interesting, I bought a tile pack from the marketplace, and now there's a "marketplace purchases" tab that shows up under search results.

Comment: I'll get back to you when I can open roll20.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? You can duplicate the map if you want multiple copies to edit (it is the double arrow tab at the top of the page). You can go to settings tab and use experimental features (transmogifier) to bring assests from other modules into different games. I believe maps that are in modules are not stored under any other tabs, but if wither of those solutions are what you want I can make an answer.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try both

Comment: Duplicating a page is probably not what I'm looking for - I'd like to know where this town map, and others I might own and simply don't realize it, are stored. I checked under both the in-game "game settings" and out of game "game settings" but didn't see anything titled "transmogifier." The in game "game settings" had "experimental features" but underneath was listed only "QR code for tablet" and "apply default settings"

Comment: I'm not a roll20 expert, but I don't think the maps and such are physically stored in a file like images you upload are. Some modules have add-ons you can insert into a current game, and it will upload the maps/content into the game. Some modules you have to start a new game and select the module as a base which will upload the maps/content to that game. If you then have multiple games you can share maps between games with transmogifier (I don't know, it is on my settings, but I have multiple games up). Anyhow, sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Ah, I got a month of Pro level subscription, and now have the Transmorgifier option.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, but I found a [guide on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=944101705) for a 3rd party program that may be of interest to you. It is about converting Roll20 purchased/free Assets to be used in the program Dungeon Painter Studio. It seems to think you should be able to download the entire pack (probably the Divine Contention pack in your case) to a Zip folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roll20 Art assets from modules and addons do not go into your Art Library. They are stored by Roll20 (using Amazon Web Services), and therefore do not count against your storage quota. This is by intention, and a good thing.

When you add an addon or create a game from a module, it creates pages for each map, usually with dynamic lighting if appropriate. This saves the end user the hassle of resizing images to fit a grid, or doing the Dynamic Lighting lines or creating light sources themselves.

If for some reason you need this graphic, you can go to the map layer, click on it and press the Z key. This calls up a large preview of the map graphic. You can right click on this image to open it in a new tab/window or to download it. To use it in another game, you will either need to add the addon or upload the graphic. At this point it *will* go into your art library, but to create a new map from it, you will need to do the sizing and any DL yourself.

Note that if you have a Pro level subscription, you can use the Transmogrifier tool to move the entire page, dynamic lighting, token, notes and all to any other game you have created.